# Spaces in directory name Bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I'm new to bash and I'm working on script that traverses the tar.gz file archive and in each file changes a string specified to an another string. Args of script: name of archive, searched string, target word.
My problem is that when archive name contains a space (e.g. I run script with following args: > change_strings.sh "/tmp/tmp.m7xYn5EQ2y/work/data txt" a A) I have following error: 
on line `if [ ! -f $filename ] ; then`  [: data: binary operator expected, dirname: extra operand `txt'. 
Here is my code:

```
  #!/bin/bash 
  filename="${1##*/}"
  VAR="$1"
  DIR=$(dirname ${VAR})
  cd "$DIR"


if [ ! -f $filename ] ; then
echo "no such archive" >&2
exit 1
fi


if ! tar tf $filename &> /dev/null; then
echo "this is not .tar.gz archive" >&2
exit 1
fi


dir=`mktemp -dt 'test.XXXXXX'`
tar -xf $filename -C $dir  #extract archive to dir
cd $dir #go to argument directory

FILES=$dir"/*"

for f in $FILES
do
sed -i "s/$2/$3/g" "$f"
done

tar -czf $filename * #create tar gz archive with files in current directory
mv -f $filename $cdir"/"$filename #move archive
rm -r $dir #remove tmp directory
```

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26574741/3776858

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `$filename` in double quotes: `"$filename"`